# linux Monit configuration escaping match pattern string

Tags: php, regex, linux, bash, escaping

I am using php and bash to generate monit configuration file `/etc/monit.conf`
I have a problem in escaping double quote and single in ignore match pattern rule

I am using php `preg_quote()` function to escape the user input text
I have try to quote the string with double quote and escaped the double quote inside with

```
\ and \\ => Error: regex parsing error:Trailing backslash
and \\\ => Error: syntax error '\*\?\[\^\]\$\'
```

---

```
## Monitoring log files 
Check file file.log with path /file/path
ignore match  "\\\+\"\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-"
if match "ERROR" then alert
```

Same thing with simple quote

```
## Monitoring log files 
Check file file.log with path /file/path
ignore match  '\\\+\'\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-'
if match "ERROR" then alert
```

in php

```
$monit_settings['SUPRESS_KEYWORDS'] = base64_encode($_POST['SUPRESS_KEYWORDS']);
write_shell_config_ini($monit_settings, "../config/monit.ini");
$script = "config-generator-monit.sh";              
exec("$script"); // i am using sudo to execute this script
```

monit.ini

```
SUPRESS_KEYWORDS="TGljZW5zZSB2YWxpZGF0aW9uIGZhaWx1cmUgLSBJbnZhbGlkIEtleSBvciBSZWdpc3RyYXRpb24gTmFtZQ=="
```

Bash script config-generator-monit.sh

```
CONFIG_FILE="/path/monit.ini"
if [[ -f $CONFIG_FILE ]]; then
    . $CONFIG_FILE
else
    echo 'Config file not found'
    exit 1
fi
echo -e 'Check file file.log with path /path/file.log' >> /etc/monit.conf
if [[ -z $SUPRESS_KEYWORDS ]]
    then
    echo 'No supression keywords for file.log'
else
    echo 'Supressing keywords' $SUPRESS_KEYWORDS
    echo -e '   ignore match "'`echo $SUPRESS_KEYWORDS | php -R 'echo base64_decode(preg_quote($argn,"\""));'`'"' >> /etc/monit.conf
fi
echo -e '   if match "ERROR" then alert' >> /etc/monit.conf
```

I have search in google for possible solution with no chance

I hope someone have resolved this before

Comment: Please share your actual code. It's hard to see where escaping is going wrong without it.

Comment: Please take a look to the new updated content and let me know if somthing wrong there